# Adding 1 to a floating point number in MIPS doesn't change the number?

Tags: floating-point, mips, cpu-architecture

In my CS homework for Computer Architecture, I ran across this interesting problem. My professor wants us to find a single-precision and a double-precision number such that when you add 1 to either of them, the number is not changed at all. Why does this make sense, and how can I go about finding these numbers??

Thanks!

Comment: What floating point format? You have to know how floating point numbers are represented in memory and what the parts mean. Then it's simple to find such numbers.

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that floating point numbers have a limited precision (the number of significant digits they can keep track of). For single precision floats that's about 7 digits, for double precision about 16 digits.

Also keep in mind that the range of floating numbers can exceed 3 x 10^38 - so clearly not all of the digits will be significant.

Comment: I know that, for single-precision, there's the 1 Sign bit, followed by 8 Exponent bits, and then the 22 Fraction bits. But how can I use that to find the number?

Comment: @roboguy12: I don't think you necessarily need to be concerned with that level of detail.  Think about what happens when you're dealing with numbers in the billions with only 3 significant digits and you add 1 to 234,000,000,000. What happens if you keep only the 3 significant digits?

Comment: @roboguy12: for single precision it's one sign + eight exponent + twenty-four mantissa = 33 bits total. Since the mantissa is left-adjusted the left-most bit will always be one and can be omitted when the number is stored in memory in a 4-byte/32-bit location.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point math is based on the binary (base 2) number system. Many answers here will speak of the precision and values from the decimal system (base 10) context. This results in (for example) the min and max values for different floating point formats taking on strange-looking values.

The 24 (1 implied + 23 explicit) bits in the single precision mantissa translate into a precision of 24 binary digits. The lowest 24-bit number where the highest bit is set is 2^23 which translates to 800000 hexadecimal or 8388608 decimal (seven significant decimal digits). The highest number where the highest bit is set is 2^24-1 which translates to ffffff hexadecimal or 16777215 (eight significant decimal digits). So now you know where the "7-8 digit precision" mentioned comes from. Personally I think the binary explanation explains things clearly whereas the decimal one often results in more questions.

If you browse this forum you will find posts that show that for certain values the "7-8 digit precision" statement is not true. If your background knowledge is entirely decimal-based you'll wonder what hit you.

With an exponent of zero (bias removed), the implicit bit (set) and the explicit bits cleared the value will be 1.00000000000000000000000 * 2^0 or 1.0 decimal. If the exponent is one the value will be 1.00000000000000000000000 * 2^1 or 2.0 decimal.

Setting the lowest bit in the mantissa means adding a value equal to 2^(exponent-23) to the 1.0 * 2^exponent. The -23 comes from the fact that the lowest bit in the mantissa is 23 positions to the right of the implicit bit i e 23 powers of two smaller than the implicit bit which is defined as being 2^exponent.

This should give you an inkling as to how the original problem could be solved.